# SwiftUI for macOS app: User @EnvironmentObject when closing a window and opening another

Tags: swiftui

My app start with a login screen were you must input credentials, if the login is successful the current window closes and another one is opened. On the new window i require some that from the user model (used during login) to perform other requests to the api (basic authentication).

Hierarchy: ContentView -> LoginView() -> MainPageView()

AppDelegateCode:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
    let userVM = CreateUserViewModel()

    // Create the window and set the content view. 
    window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.center()
    window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(userVM))
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

ContentView code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    LoginView()
}
```

}

LoginView code:

```
struct LoginView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userVM: CreateUserViewModel
//@ObservedObject var userVM: CreateUserViewModel = CreateUserViewModel()
@State private var showSignUpSheet: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {

        Text("LubeMarker")
            .font(.title)

        HStack {
            Text("Email")
            TextField("", text: self.$userVM.email)
        }
        HStack {
            Text("Pass")
                .padding([.trailing], 4)
            SecureField("", text: self.$userVM.password)
        }

        HStack {
            Button("Login") {

                self.userVM.loginUser()


                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    if self.userVM.loginUserMessage == "Login Successful" {
                        NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()

                        let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 480, height: 300), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
                        window.center()
                        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Primary Window")
                        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: MainPageView().environmentObject(self.userVM))
                        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
                    }
                }

            }
            Button("Sign Up") {
                self.showSignUpSheet = true
            }
        }
        Text(userVM.loginUserMessage)
    }
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 60)
    //.frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSignUpSheet) {
        SignUpView(showSingUpSheet: self.$showSignUpSheet)
    }
}
```

}

When i want to use the @EnvironmentObject in a child view of MainPageView i encounter the following error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type CreateUserViewModel found. 
A View.environmentObject(_:) for CreateUserViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

I assume that the error is a result of the fact that there is no parent-child relation between LoginView and MainPageView because i closed the window and opened another in the login button action block.

Is there a way to link the two views in swiftUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. In the LoginView I declared an instance of CreateUserViewModel with the @ObservedObject property wrapper and passed it to the MainPageView, that required to also add a new property in the MainPageView of type CreateUserViewModel.

LoginView:

```
@ObservedObject var userVM: CreateUserViewModel = CreateUserViewModel()
@State private var showSignUpSheet: Bool = false

var body: some View {

        HStack {
            Button("Login") {

                self.userVM.loginUser()

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {

                    if self.userVM.loginUserMessage == "Login Successful" {

                        let mainPage = MainPageView(userVM: self.userVM)
                        NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()

                        let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 480, height: 300), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
                        window.center()
                        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Primary Window")
                        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: mainPage)
                        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
                    }
```

MainPageView:

```
struct MainPageView: View {

@State var selectedProduct: ProductTypes?
@State var showAddProductSheet: Bool = false

var userVM: CreateUserViewModel

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        HStack {

            Button("Add Product") {
                self.showAddProductSheet = true
            }
            .padding()

            Spacer()

            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 480, minHeight: 300)
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showAddProductSheet) {
        AddProductView(showAddProductSheet: self.$showAddProductSheet).environmentObject(self.userVM)
    }
}
```

}

And from the MainPageView a passed the userVM as an environmental object to other views. I seem that you can only bridge a closing window with a new one by only using @ObservedObject.

I'm still curios if there is a way to use @EnvironmentObject in this scenario.